# Order of Operation in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have the below query selecting items and one of its feature from a hundred thousand row of items.

But I am concerned about the performance of sub query.  Will it be executed after or before the where clause ?

Suppose, I am selecting 25 items from 10000 items, this subquery will be executed only for 25 items or 10000 items ?

```
declare @BlockStart int = 1
    , @BlockSize int = 25
;
select *, (
    select Value_Float
    from Features B
    where B.Feature_ModelID = Itm.ModelID
        and B.Feature_PropertyID = 5
    ) as Price  
from (
    select *
        , row_number() over (order by ModelID desc) as RowNumber
    from Models
) Itm 
where Itm.RowNumber >= @BlockStart
    and Itm.RowNumber < @BlockStart + @BlockSize
order by ModelID desc
```

Comment: Look at the execution plan. That is a good starting point.

Comment: The `where` filters before the `select` (in general) so it is probably one 25 times.

Comment: Select part of the query executed after where part, that's why subquery at the select part only works for the 25 records. but it does not mean it executed 25 times. probably it will be executed one time for 25 records.

Comment: Why not `OFFSET @BlockStart ROWS FETCH NEXT @BlockSize ROWS ONLY`  instead of using a where clause to determine the same thing? I do think you need to put the numbers in the query, not as parameters, I think it errors if you try that (since a variable can change as part of execution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub query in the `FROM` clause produces a full set of results, but the sub query in the `SELECT` clause will (**generally!**) only be run for the records included with the final result set.

As with all things SQL, there is a query optimizer involved, which may at times decide to create seemingly-strange execution plans. In this case, I believe we can be pretty confident, but I need to caution about making sweeping generalizations about SQL language order of operations.

Moving on, have you seen the `OFFSET/FECTH` syntax available in Sql Server 2012 and later? This seems like a better way to handle the `@BlockStart` and `@BlockSize` values, especially as [it looks like you're paging on the clustered key.](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) (If you end up paging on an alternate column, the link shows a **much** faster method).

Also, at risk of making generalizations again, if you can know that only one `Features` record exists per `ModelID` with `Feature_PropertyID = 5`, you *will* tend to get better performance using a JOIN:

```
SELECT m.*, f.Value_Float As Price
FROM Models m
LEFT JOIN Features f ON f.Feature_ModelID = m.ModelID AND f.Feature_PropertyID = 5
ORDER BY m.ModelID DESC
OFFSET @BlockStart ROWS FETCH NEXT @BlockSize ROWS ONLY
```

If you can't make that guarantee, you *may* get better performance from an APPLY operation:

```
SELECT m.*, f.Value_Float As Price
FROM Models m
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Value_Float 
    FROM Features f 
    WHERE f.Feature_ModelID = m.ModelID AND f.Feature_PropertyID = 5
) f
ORDER BY m.ModelID DESC
OFFSET @BlockStart ROWS FETCH NEXT @BlockSize ROWS ONLY
```

Finally, this smells like yet another variation of the Entity-Attribute-Value pattern... which, while it has it's places, typically should be a pattern of last resort.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, you can. Go try it.

Comment: I guess you can now, still though your start should be -1 due to the >= in the original query